# Using Python to manipulate data from a CSV only applying it to the first result

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV I'm attempting to build a small python script for that will 'convert' it to CSV (basically to prepare data into an acceptable format).

I'm hitting a bit of a road block as I need to detect the first result out of 'blocks' of results;

for example

```
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
EEFFGGHHII-2.4-5.6-7.5
```

The first part (preceding the dash) has a variable length and is the only way to detect an 'individual' listing in the particular database. I basically want to insert a flag in a separate column which identifies each cluster that share the same code.

There are several hundred thousand listings so I can't come up with a list to just search through.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am so confused for some reason. You have a CSV and you want a differently formatted CSV... and you want to assign a group ID to the first "column" (everything before the first dash), and have that in a final, last column... for each row...?  so, each row with `AABBCCDD` would get 1 or something...? And tell me more about the database you mentioned... and its role.

Comment: Would you show concrete example ? it's a little bit confusing as  gloomy.penguin mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; basically they are product variations (different sizes/colors) and the first part of the SKU is a unique code they share. I'm trying to import the data into MAGMI (for Magento) however due to the nature of the import one product out of each of these must be marked as 'visible' while the rest are not visible (i.e. the aim is that only one product shows up while the rest will still exist in the database). The column that will have the flag (1 indicating it should be shown/searchable) doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Another way to explain it as follows;
SHIRT-RED, SHIRT-BLUE, SHIRT-GREEN, SHOE-RED, SHOE-BLUE
From these only the first listing from shirts (SHIRT-RED, SHOE-BLUE) would have a flag applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is grouped as shown, `itertools.groupby` can iterate ordered data grouping by a common key:

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator

data1 = '''\
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
EEFFGGHHII-2.4-5.6-7.5
'''

data2 = '''\
SHIRT-RED
SHIRT-BLUE
SHIRT-GREEN
SHOE-RED
SHOE-BLUE
'''

def setup():
    '''Generate some sample input files.'''
    with open('sample1.hsv','w') as f:
        f.write(data1)
    with open('sample2.hsv','w') as f:
        f.write(data2)

def process(infile,outfile):
    with open(infile,'r',newline='') as ifile, open(outfile,'w',newline='') as ofile:
        r = csv.reader(ifile,delimiter='-')
        w = csv.writer(ofile,delimiter=',')

        # key is the first column (offset 0)
        # group is an iterator over the lines that have the same key
        for key,group in itertools.groupby(r,operator.itemgetter(0)):
            # Add a final column to the row list.  1 for first item.
            w.writerow(next(group) + [1])
            # Remaining items in group get a zero value in new column.
            for other in group:
                w.writerow(other + [0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    process('sample1.hsv','sample1.csv')
    process('sample2.hsv','sample2.csv')
```

#### Results:

sample1.hsv

```
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6
EEFFGGHHII-2.4-5.6-7.5
```

sample1.csv

```
AABBCCDD,1.2,2.4,2.6,1
AABBCCDD,1.2,2.4,2.6,0
AABBCCDD,1.2,2.4,2.6,0
AABBCCDD,1.2,2.4,2.6,0
EEFFGGHHII,2.4,5.6,7.5,1
```

sample2.hsv

```
SHIRT-RED
SHIRT-BLUE
SHIRT-GREEN
SHOE-RED
SHOE-BLUE
```

sample2.csv

```
SHIRT,RED,1
SHIRT,BLUE,0
SHIRT,GREEN,0
SHOE,RED,1
SHOE,BLUE,0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a set containing the ids that have been read. Something like this:

```
read_ids = set()

for row in input_csv:
    if row[0] in read_ids:
        flag = 0
    else:
        read_ids.add(row[0])
        flag = 1

    output_csv.write(...) # Use flag
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I didn't understand your questions clearly as it's ambiguous. But i tried to work on what you described above.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

example= "AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6 AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6 AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6 AABBCCDD-1.2-2.4-2.6 EEFFGGHHII-2.4-5.6-7.5"

exampleList= re.split(" |-",example )

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [ x for index,x in enumerate(exampleList) if index%4== 0],
                    'B' : [ x for index,x in enumerate(exampleList) if index%4== 1],
                    'C' : [ x for index,x in enumerate(exampleList) if index%4== 2],
                    'D' : [ x for index,x in enumerate(exampleList) if index%4== 3]})
```

Result:

```
Splitted data 

    ['AABBCCDD', '1.2', '2.4', '2.6', 'AABBCCDD', '1.2', '2.4', '2.6', 'AABBCCDD', '1.2', '2.4', '2.6', 'AABBCCDD', '1.2', '2.4', '2.6', 'EEFFGGHHII', '2.4', '5.6', '7.5']


CSV 
                A    B    C    D
    0    AABBCCDD  1.2  2.4  2.6
    1    AABBCCDD  1.2  2.4  2.6
    2    AABBCCDD  1.2  2.4  2.6
    3    AABBCCDD  1.2  2.4  2.6
    4  EEFFGGHHII  2.4  5.6  7.5
```

Then I tried to group data based on column B. 
First, I stored the unique values in the column B to give to everyone an index.
Then, I regrouped values and gave to everyone an index (based on the previous stored types)

```
t= list(set(df.B.values))
print t

df['groups']= [t.index(w) for w in df.groupby('B')['B'].apply(lambda x:x)]


print df

           A    B    C    D  groups
0    AABBCCDD  1.2  2.4  2.6       0
1    AABBCCDD  1.2  2.4  2.6       0
2    AABBCCDD  1.2  2.4  2.6       0
3    AABBCCDD  1.2  2.4  2.6       0
4  EEFFGGHHII  2.4  5.6  7.5       1
```

Now for every group, you should select two to make them visible

```
def firstIndex(k):
   for i in xrange(max(df.groups)): 
     l= [y for index, y in enumerate(df.groups) if y=x]
     genL+= l[:k]
   return genL

l= firstIndex(2)
oList= [1 if x in l else 0 for x in df.groups  ]

df['Flag']= oList
```

To exporte the data to CSV file, you can simple use pandas to_csv

```
df.to_csv(name)
```